# Regular expression. Use the same character in two occurances

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this
`( ( ( some text here`

I want to remove spaces between two parentheses. I am trying to use regular expression for it:

```
value.replace(/\( \(/g, "((");
```

But this statement removes only first space, so resulting string is:
`(( ( some text here`

As i understand, regExp uses second parentheses only for first occurance. I want to make regExp use that parentheses for both occurance. So my desired result is:
   `((( some text here`

Is it possible to make this by regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.replace(/\( \(/g, "((")`](https://regex101.com/r/3GwCMd/1) replacement does not work because the two `(` chars are *consumed*. In order to make sure you match *consecutive* space-separated `(` chars, you need to make sure the second `(` is only checked for presence and not *consumed*. That is when lookarounds come to the rescue.

You may use `.replace(/\(\s+(?=\()/g, '('))` to replace 1+ whitespaces only if they are followed with `(`:

```js
var s = "( ( ( some text here";
console.log(s.replace(/\(\s+(?=\()/g, '('));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3GwCMd/2).

**Pattern details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (NOTE: if you only need to remove *single* spaces between the `(` chars, replace with the single space, or `\s`)
- `(?=\()` - a *positive lookahead* that makes sure there is a `(` char immediately to the right of the current location (but this `(` is not consumed, and thus is not removed).

Comment: I was hoping for something like, *in first match `( (` is captured and processed. So now the regex will start looking from ` ( some text here`. Hence, it is not processed.*

Comment: @Rajesh `( (` are not captured, they are matched and *consumed*, i.e. added to the match value and make the regex engine advance the regex index. It is set right after the match value, so the second `(` cannot be matched again.